# Finding the minimum and maximum value from an array in a JSON File in p5.js

Tags: json, max, p5.js, minimum

I have a JSON data showing the bus shelters of Gold Coast

this is my data = https://data.gov.au/geoserver/gold-coast/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=ckan_be880d63_175a_4383_b0f2_ef88b831eba9&outputFormat=json

from there I want to find out the minimum and maximum latitude and longitude using p5.js and plot them on the graph
here is my code up until now

```
function preload(){
  shelters = loadJSON('https://data.gov.au/geoserver/gold-coast/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=ckan_be880d63_175a_4383_b0f2_ef88b831eba9&outputFormat=json')
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400`enter code here`);
  print(shelters)
  noLoop()
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  bus  = shelters.features
  max_min()
  
}

function max_min(){
  for(let i = 0; i < bus.length; i ++ ){
    latitudes = createDiv('h1', bus[i].geometry.coordinate)
    max_lat = Math.max(latitudes)
  }
  console.log(...max_lat)
}
```

I am having trouble finding the max and min latitude and longitude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few things which can't work in your code, let's first have a look at that:

- First, in your ``` createCanvas(400, 400``enter code here``); ``` lines you have a syntax error here, you need to remove the `enter code here` string.
- Then in your `max_min()` function, you iterate on all the buses and get `bus[i].geometry.coordinate`. My understanding is that this is an array containing the latitude and longitude of the bus, so using `Math.max` on this array will return the max value between the latitude and the longitude of the current bus, which is not what you want.

You have several options to do what you want. If you really want to use `Math.max()` and `Math.min()` and are familiar with `map` you could:

- Build an array of all the latitudes: `bus.map(b => b.geometry.coordinates[0])` i.e take all the items in the `bus` array and transform that to an array with only the first item of each buse's `geometry.coordinates` property. (replace `[0]` by `[1]` to get the longitude)
- Deconstruct it with the `...` operator because `Math.max()` doesn't take an array but a list of arguments
- And assign that to a value, you function would look like this:

```
function max_min() {
    const maxLat = Math.max(...bus.map(b => b.geometry.coordinates[0]));
    const minLat = Math.min(...bus.map(b => b.geometry.coordinates[0]));
    const maxLong = Math.max(...bus.map(b => b.geometry.coordinates[1]));
    const minLong = Math.min(...bus.map(b => b.geometry.coordinates[1]));

    return { maxLat, minLat, maxLong, minLong };
}
```

Here the code is short but you iterate 4 times over the `bus` array, which is not especially efficient. So you could also take another approach where you would create a short helper function to get the latitude and longitude of a bus:

```
// Given a feature return its latitude and longitude in an object
function getLatLong(feature) {
    const [lat, long] = feature.geometry.coordinates;
    return { lat, long };
}
```

And then iterate over all the buses and given these information update the min and max values like this:

```
// Find the max and min longitude and latitude and return them in an object
function max_min() {
    // Use the first feature of the list to initialize the max and min values
    const { lat: firstLat, long: firstLong } = getLatLong(bus[0]);
    let maxLat = firstLat;
    let minLat = firstLat;
    let maxLong = firstLong;
    let minLong = firstLong;

    // Iterate through all the features to update the max and min values
    for (let i = 1; i < bus.length; i++) {
        const { lat, long } = getLatLong(bus[i]);
        if (lat > maxLat) {
            maxLat = lat;
        }
        if (lat < minLat) {
            minLat = lat;
        }
        if (long > maxLong) {
            maxLong = long;
        }
        if (long < minLong) {
            minLong = long;
        }
    }

    // Return the updated max and min values
    return { maxLat, minLat, maxLong, minLong };
}
```

Finally in `draw()` you can do whatever you want with them, for the example I only write them in the canvas:

```
function draw() {
    background(220);

    // Get the max and min values with our helper function
    const { maxLat, minLat, maxLong, minLong } = max_min();

    // Show the values
    text(`max lat ${maxLat}`, 0, 10);
    text(`min lat ${minLat}`, 0, 30);
    text(`max long ${maxLong}`, 0, 50);
    text(`min long ${minLong}`, 0, 70);
}
```

I created [this codepen](https://codepen.io/statox/pen/MWjGvBL?editors=0011) with the complete code working so that you can have a look at how the parts work together.

Comment: Thank you so muchh!!!! This was literally really helpful!!!

Comment: also now, sorry for bothering, do you know how I can plot dots on the buses using the map function?

Comment: You have a lot of different ways to do it: The map function would allow you to get only the data you need to plot (e.g. transforming your list of bus to a simple list of coordinates) but then it's really up to you. You use p5js to show the image of a map and somehow convert latitude/longitude to pixels, if you want a chart you could use [char.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) instead of p5... You will have to do a bit of research, try a first implementation and if you're stuck post another question about a precise issue that you have trouble to solve.

Comment: I think that a question like "How to show locations on a map" might get closed as "too broad" on SO

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65579759/how-to-plot-dots-based-on-the-coordinates-from-a-given-data-on-a-canvas

Comment: I posted a question, will you be able to help me?

Comment: As I said your new question is very vague: Anyone who would want to answer it would need to do a lot of research on their own. I think it's unlikely that you get an answer unless to first propose a more precise solution.